# Magento 2.4 upgrade error

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I am upgrading Magento **2.4.2** to **2.4.3**

on `composer update` I am facing these issues

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 4.1.1
    - Installation request for magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.6.0, 3.6.1].
    - Installation request for allure-framework/allure-phpunit ~1.2.0 -> satisfiable by allure-framework/allure-phpunit[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3 requires ramsey/uuid ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[4.1.0, 4.1.1].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3 requires ramsey/uuid ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[4.1.0, 4.1.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install ramsey/uuid 4.1.0
    - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.3].
```

any way to fix it ?

Comment: I think I had this one. Do you have a replace section at the bottom of the composer.json? Try removing it.

Comment: No i have not replace or edit composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check composer version if its not 2 then update it.
Magento 2.4.3 requires 2.x composer version.

```
sudo composer self-update --2

composer install
```

Comment: I installed it with 1.7 so its not really required to be 2.0

Comment: See : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html